# Unable to apt-get update /upgrade /installl Ubuntu 14.04 -Method bzip2 has died unexpectedly

Tags: 14.04, apt

Unable to update/upgrade/install Ubuntu 14.04, and it shows the below:

```
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en [4,089 kB] 
E: Method bzip2 has died unexpectedly!
 E: Sub-process bzip2 received signal 25.
```

Also while upgrading - shows '0%':

I was fixing as error ' sts...0% ' while upgrading Ubuntu. I tried creating a manual sources.list. I reverted the changes to the file, but the error is still there.

Below is the result of apt-get update --print-uris

```
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/source/Sources.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_source_Sources 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/source/Sources.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_source_Sources 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/source/Sources.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_source_Sources 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/source/Sources.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_source_Sources 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease' security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_InRelease 0
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_source_Sources 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_restricted_source_Sources 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_source_Sources 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/source/Sources.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_source_Sources 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_restricted_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_restricted_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_restricted_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_InRelease 0
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_source_Sources 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/source/Sources.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_source_Sources 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/source/Sources.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_universe_source_Sources 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/source/Sources.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_source_Sources 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_universe_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_InRelease 0
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/source/Sources.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_main_source_Sources 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/source/Sources.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_restricted_source_Sources 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/source/Sources.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_universe_source_Sources 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/source/Sources.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_multiverse_source_Sources 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_main_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_universe_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_main_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_restricted_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_universe_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_restricted_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_restricted_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_universe_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en.bz2' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_universe_i18n_Translation-en 0 :
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease' us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_InRelease 0
```

And below is the output of apt-get update now

```
myprompt:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en_US
myprompt:~$ sts... 0%
```

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Or something that can intercept your internet traffic?

Comment: ssh,http& https are open- others are blocked via iptables.

Comment: Manually changed the sources.list , stil showing ' Reading package lists...0% '

Comment: What did you change it to? Can you post it to http://paste.ubuntu.com and add the link to the question? You could also run `apt-get` with the `--print-uris` options, which will just output the links it tries to download instead of actually downloading them. Then test by trying to manually get some of those files.

Comment: Tried the command , but results shows 'apt-get --print-uris is not understood'

Comment: `--print-uris` is an option for `install`,`update`, etc. So the full command is `sudo apt-get update --print-uris`. Sorry I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Results of apt-get update --print-uris & apt-get update .. added

Comment: Can you download any of those links manually and open them? That we can figure out if there's something interfering with your connection to the mirrors.

Comment: $wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages.bz2
--2014-07-05 17:1
Resolving security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.88.153, 91.189.91.13, 91.189.91.14, ...
Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.153|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 101532 (99K) [application/x-bzip2]
Saving to: ‘Packages.bz2’
100%===================================================================================>] 101,532--.-K/sin 0.03s
2014-07-05 17:13:21 (3.32 MB/s) - ‘Packages.bz2’ saved [101532/101532]

Comment: seems connecting and saving successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run :

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the resulting Gedit file, replace all starts with `deb ://` or `http://` with `deb http://` (not `#deb http://`)

Save the Gedit and Close.

Comment: myprompt:~$ gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
   The program 'gksudo' is currently not installed. You can  install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gksu
   myprompt:~$ sudo apt-get install gksu
   myprompt:~$ sts... 0%

Comment: can i edit using Vi ?

Comment: Sources.list is already starts with ' deb http:// ' or either with 'deb-src http://'

Comment: Restored to previous version from back up .. updates are running fine now - sources.list could be the problem .. I am monitoring the same ..

Comment: @Shaishav congrats.